# Google's preferred method for interacting with Calendar: API or GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

To interact with my Google Calendar, I appear to have two options:

The API - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/
or
Google Apps Script - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/

I can do similar things with each - create, delete and update calendars and events.

Does Google have a preferred way for us to interact with Calendar (or Contacts, or anything else)? Is Google Apps Script or the API likely to have a longer life span? Is it wiser to choose one form of interacting with Calendar over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is used for interacting with outside applications and comes in multiple different programming languages. Google Apps Scripts is simpler to use, but only works to make one google app to talk to another and is only offered in javascript.

Basically, if you want to build a program that accesses Google use the API. If you want to get your calendar to talk to your Google Spreadsheet, use the Google-Apps-Script